# How to produce an EVA report

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm in carreer mode, I've finally managed to reach the orbit, I see the EVA button, but when I'm outside the only thing I can do is to climb the ladder up and down and eventually get lost in space :)

I read a [few](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Science) [pages](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/EVA) of the [wiki](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Antenna), but I can't find the way to produce an EVA report.

Any help please?

And to send the report back with the antenna?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You generate the EVA report in a similar way as any other experiment or crew report. When you are performing EVA, right click your astronaut and you should see an option "EVA report". Now you just have to keep the data and get back into the ship. From there you can either transmit it (with 100% efficiency) or keep it until you land back on Kerbin.

Comment: Pretty sure EVA reports only get [50% transmission efficiency](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Science#EVA_Reports), and it may even be lower than that due to transmission caps.

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll check, although I am pretty sure I saw it with 100% efficiency.

Comment: Thank you, it worked :) Yes, I see 50% efficiency, but I don't even have a comm device...

Comment: Heeere I am. http://i.imgur.com/2R3kmyD.jpg during the EVA and http://i.imgur.com/VL5BykD.jpg once back inside the ship. Only the basic antenna is equipped. The version is 0.23.0.395, in which science received a lot of tweaks.

Comment: @Humungus huh, I wouldn't have thought would been changed.  The wiki is still out of date, and I haven't played in .23 yet.

Comment: One of the biggest changes in 0.23 was changing the science system so that you can't get away with repeatedly sampling and transmitting. Also the Science Jr. and goo container need a new part in order to be re-prepped after transmitting data.

Comment: As KSP is very much in development, with major updates hitting every couple of months - checking these facts are definitely best done in the game, rather than from a wiki source.